# Angular: Form-Submit should forward to new component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two components. In the app.component.ts users have a form in which they can enter data. If you then click the Submit button, you should be forwarded to an app.show.component.ts, but I don't know how to make this link.

```
<button mat-raised-button fxFlex type="submit" color="accent">Submit configuration</button>
```

Can someone please fix it?

Comment: your question is too broad, but you could just redirect your user in your form submit handler by router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if by forward you mean that you should load a new page, then you can use navigate method from Router module when the data is submitted:

HTML

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="onSubmit()" fxFlex type="submit" color="accent">Submit configuration</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  onSubmit() {
    this.router.navigate('/show')
  }
}
```

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShowComponent } from './show/show.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
  },
{
    path: '/show',
    component: ShowComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Might seem complicated, at first, but there is a lot of articles and documentation about Angular Routing.

[Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for something like this